# Oracle Other options than SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sys-refcursor

I have joining  multiple tables and returning data from a stored procedure using a SYS_REFCURSOR.
Now the calling program does not want to use SYS_REFCURSOR. What are the other options to return the data?
Data is 200000 records and 11 columns

Answer (score 1):

1. Pipelined functions: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions
2. Implicit resultsets: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1
3. Polymorphic Table Functions: https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/polymorphic-table-functions-18c